# Diagnostic: Autodata newest version

Tags: maintenance, troubleshooting

I have seen people using autodata for general information about cars, like how to fix a timing belt for particular types of cars. But the version that was being used only had up to cars made in 2009 and before. I was thinking of purchasing this but with more up to date version... So is there an autodata version which has more up to date information (cars manufactured in 2011 or even 2012)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google is your friend when you have questions: http://www.autodatapubs.com/2012-AIS-DVD-p/12-dvdis.htm

So yes, autodata 2012 has car models through 2012.

Comment: was looking at autodata 2012 but could not find any information on this when ever I looked online! cheers